# Entity Framework. Не работает каскадное удаление

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Framework 6, Code First, SQLite

Есть дерево категорий. Если удалить категорию, которая включает в себя подкатегории, подкатегории не удаляются каскадно. Они по прежнему имеют `ParentId`, указывающий на уже не существующую категорию.

Модель ссылающаяся на себя:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Конфигурация:

```
public class CategoryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Title).IsRequired();

        HasOptional(p => p.Parent)
            .WithMany(p => p.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

Таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE Categories
(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Title nvarchar NOT NULL,
    SortOrder int NOT NULL,
    ParentId int,
    FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES Categories (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX IX_Category_ParentId ON Categories (ParentId)
```

Метод удаления категории:

```
public void Delete(Category category)
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        var entity = db.Categories.Find(category.Id);
        if (entity != null)
        {
            db.Categories.Remove(entity);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Подскажите, почему не происходит каскадного удаления?

Comment: 'WillCascadeOnDelete(true)' не имеет смысла, так как по умолчанию делается true

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk это если внешний ключ зависимой сущности не представляет собой тип `Nullable`. Однако у нас как раз `Nullable` -
 `HasOptional(p => p.Parent)`, поэтому по умолчанию `ON DELETE CASCADE` не добавляется в таблицу и необходимо указать `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в следующем: в SQLite по умолчанию отключена поддержка ограничения внешних ключей.

Для ее включения необходимо установить `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`.

Это можно сделать, изменив строку подключения `ConnectionString` в конфиге:

```
data source=C:\Dbs\myDb.db;foreign keys=true;
```