# Однако найти поставщик базы данных Entity Framework, совместимой с этой версией, для вашего подключения к данным не удалось

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добрый вечер. Бьюсь об стену какую  неделю. Не могу подключить БД SQLite. У меня visual studio 2017. Пробовал добавлять разные Entity Framework в ссылки, но результат тот же. Делал по [инструкции](http://emrehanay.com/c-winforms-sqlite-kullanimi-vs-2013vs-2015/) , мой App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings></connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"></defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.105.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.99.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: А сам провайдер установлен? [Попробуйте переустановить.](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Comment: Chloroform Спасибо буду пробовать. Но там 2015 sqlite-netFx46-static-binary-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.105.2.zip  и это меня смущает. Роль для visual studio 2017, Есть или нет ?

Comment: Про какую роль вы говорите, не могу понять?
Там можно скачать пакет для Nuget: `System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.105.2.nupkg`  попробуйте подтянуть этот пакет, может будет достаточно.

Comment: Chloroform Я предположил что в названии sqlite-netFx46-static-binary-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.105.2.zip . 2015 - это версия visual studio. Потому что есть Visual Studio 2005, Visual Studio 2008 и так далее. А  поддержка для Visual Studio 2017 еще не вышла. Могу ошибаться

Comment: "The Visual C++ 2015 Update 3 runtime for x64 is statically linked. " - Это рантайм который устанавливается вместе с Visual Studio. Проверьте - установлен или нет

Answer (score 2):

Если подойдет подход `CodeFirst`, вот пример подключения к SQLite для EF6.
Я пользуюсь зависимостью [SQLite.CodeFirst](https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst)

---

1) Добавляем через NuGet библиотеку `SQLite.CodeFirst`
2) Заполняем `app.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqliteConnection" connectionString="data source=.\data.db;" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.105.1" newVersion="1.0.105.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.105.1" newVersion="1.0.105.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Обратите внимание на блок

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqliteConnection" connectionString="data source=.\data.db;" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Название подключения `SqliteConnection`, бд будет располагаться в папке проекта `.\data.db;`

3) Создаем класс `DbContextInitializer`

```
public class DbContextInitializer : SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
{
    public DbContextInitializer(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) : base(modelBuilder)
    {
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext ctx)
    {
    }
}
```

4) Создаем класс контекста

```
public sealed class MyDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    // Прописываем DbSet для моделей
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext() : base("SqliteConnection") // указываем название нашего подключения
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Указываем инициализатор из шага 3
        Database.SetInitializer(new DbContextInitializer(modelBuilder));
    }
}
```

---

Пару замечаний по работе с EF и SQLite:

1. Для SQLite не реализована поддержка миграций
2. В SQLite по умолчанию отключена поддержка ограничения внешних ключей, при необходимости можно [включить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683293/entity-framework-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/683300#683300)